# How to benchmark two different versions of the same non-NuGet library in BenchmarkDotNet?

Tags: benchmarkdotnet

I'm trying to use BenchmarkDotNet to prepare performance regression testing for a library. This requires that I compare the same tests with an older (stable) version of the library. Now, there's an option to give [different versions of a NuGet package to a job](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/samples/IntroNuGet.html). There doesn't seem to be an option to reference different assemblies instead.

I've tried custom build configurations:

```
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Baseline'">
    <Reference Include="MyAssembly">
      <HintPath>lib\baseline\MyAssembly.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' != 'Baseline'">
    <Reference Include="MyAssembly">
      <HintPath>lib\current\MyAssembly.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

but when trying to use those configurations from BenchmarkDotNet via

```
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
      var summary = BenchmarkRunner.Run(typeof(Program).Assembly,
        DefaultConfig.Instance
          .With(Job.Default.WithCustomBuildConfiguration("Baseline"))
          .With(Job.Default.WithCustomBuildConfiguration("Current")));
    }
```

I get build errors that indicate that the assembly is not referenced at all. BenchmarkDotNet also helpfully clears up any temporary artifacts it creates so I can't even look at the generated project file to figure out how that looked.

Would the only workaround here be to wrap the library in a NuGet package? Or is there something I'm overlooking in the (for this case seemingly sparse) docs?

[This issue](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet/issues/1197) seems to be vaguely related to the build errors I'm getting.

Comment: Which Framework do you target? How do you run it exactly from command prompt? Could you post the error that you get? Or create a small GitHub repo with a repro case?

Comment: BTW when using custom build configurations you need to remember to enable optimizations, which by default are enabled only for Release (it's MSBuild behaviour)

```xml
<Optimize>true</Optimize>
```

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get something similar working, which may also work for you. In my case, I wanted to reference both the NuGet and the local project from the *same* build of the benchmark project.

After adding both the `PackageReference` and the `ProjectReference`, I (manually) added the `Aliases` to the `ProjectReference`:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\src\Combinatorics\Combinatorics.csproj" Aliases="localbuild" />
</ItemGroup>
```

The dll names do need to be different (since both dlls end up in the output directory). So I changed the dll name for the referenced project (but only when building locally and not when doing a continuous integration build):

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <AssemblyName Condition="'$(CI)'!='true'">local.Combinatorics</AssemblyName>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Then I could use `extern alias` and `using` to use both assemblies in the same app:

```
extern alias localbuild;
using NugetCombinatorics = Combinatorics.Collections;
using LocalCombinatorics = localbuild::Combinatorics.Collections;

...

[BenchmarkCategory("Enumerate"), Benchmark(Baseline = true)]
public void EnumerateOld()
{
    var permutations = new NugetCombinatorics.Permutations<int>(_source);
    foreach (var p in permutations)
        ;
}

[BenchmarkCategory("Enumerate"), Benchmark]
public void EnumerateNew()
{
    var permutations = new LocalCombinatorics.Permutations<int>(_source);
    foreach (var p in permutations)
        ;
}
```

The duplicated code is not ideal, and I'm kinda abusing categories instead of using proper runs, but it gets the job done.